# R Loop Through Multiple Columns and Multiply by Value in A List

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I have a list with ten items:

```
 Discount <- c(1.00, 0.97, 0.94, 0.92, 0.89, 0.86, 0.84, 0.81, 0.79, 0.77)
```

I also have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
 x <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,10,rep=TRUE)))

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  20 30 32 28 50 32 42  9 11  50
2   8 32 37 34 21 35 19 48 30  11
3  16 32 19 22 45  5 33  8 25  28
4  36  8 41 40 15  2  8  5 17  33
5  17 17  5  6 43 11 30  3 27  21
6   7 40 21  3 28 17 35 19 23  23
7  40 21 39 48 13  7 49 34  7  20
8  34 15 50 14 33 13 35 12 23  46
9  26 18 49  6  2 20 15 44 10  12
10 29 19  9 39 29 15  9 27  4   6
```

I would like to multiply column X1 by the first item in the list, column X2 by the second column in the list, and so on.  X1-X10 represent years and I am discounting the dollar values. Lastly, I would like to sum up the total of all of those products.

The code I have tried is:

```
 for( i in 1:length(x)){
   for(j in length(Discount)){

     New <- x %>% mutate(Discount_Sum =  sum(x[, i] * Discount[, j]))
   }
 }
```

This code runs, but the values in Discount_Sum are all the same. How can I make it so that all the values are different as they should be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can replicate the 'Discount' by the `col`um index of 'x' and do the multiplication in a vectorized way in `R` (no need of loops)

```
x1 <- x * Discount[col(x)]
```

Then, we use `rowSums` if we need the sum by row

```
rowSums(x1)
```

Or use `colSums` for column wise sum

```
colSums(x1)
```

---

Another option is to convert to `matrix` and then do `%*%`

```
as.vector(as.matrix(x) %*% Discount)
#[1] 266.72 240.90 205.00 183.78 156.57 188.51 248.41 241.69 179.40 167.69
```

---

Or another option is

```
x1 <- sweep(x, 2, Discount, `*`)
rowSums(x1)
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(X1 = c(20L, 8L, 16L, 36L, 17L, 7L, 40L, 34L, 26L, 
29L), X2 = c(30L, 32L, 32L, 8L, 17L, 40L, 21L, 15L, 18L, 19L), 
    X3 = c(32L, 37L, 19L, 41L, 5L, 21L, 39L, 50L, 49L, 9L), X4 = c(28L, 
    34L, 22L, 40L, 6L, 3L, 48L, 14L, 6L, 39L), X5 = c(50L, 21L, 
    45L, 15L, 43L, 28L, 13L, 33L, 2L, 29L), X6 = c(32L, 35L, 
    5L, 2L, 11L, 17L, 7L, 13L, 20L, 15L), X7 = c(42L, 19L, 33L, 
    8L, 30L, 35L, 49L, 35L, 15L, 9L), X8 = c(9L, 48L, 8L, 5L, 
    3L, 19L, 34L, 12L, 44L, 27L), X9 = c(11L, 30L, 25L, 17L, 
    27L, 23L, 7L, 23L, 10L, 4L), X10 = c(50L, 11L, 28L, 33L, 
    21L, 23L, 20L, 46L, 12L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

Discount <- c(1, 0.97, 0.94, 0.92, 0.89, 0.86, 0.84, 0.81, 0.79, 0.77)
```

Comment: Various solutions! Love your gallery of answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one for loop if `x` and `Discount` have the same number of elements, in this case ten values and ten columns and store in a vector the results:

```
#Data
Discount <- c(1.00, 0.97, 0.94, 0.92, 0.89, 0.86, 0.84, 0.81, 0.79, 0.77)
x <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:50,10,rep=TRUE)))
#Empty vector
vec <- c()
#Loop
for(i in 1:ncol(x))
{
  vec[i] <- sum(x[,i]*Discount[i],na.rm = T)
}
#Total sum
sum(vec)
```

Comment: Is there a way to create the sum in a new column within object/data frame x?

Comment: @ldan you could use `cbind(x,vec)`

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option might be using `unlist`+ `rep`

```
x[] <- unlist(x) * rep(Discount, each = nrow(x))
```